Integration of a list of data
I've got a list of data, for instance:
{{733.376, 0}, {740.71, 3.7816*10^-6}, {748.044, 
  4.1438*10^-6}, {755.378, 4.5425*10^-6}, {762.711, 
  4.9811*10^-6}, {770.045, 5.4641*10^-6}, {777.379, 
  5.996*10^-6}, {784.713, 6.5824*10^-6}, {792.046, 
  7.2289*10^-6}, {799.38, 7.9423*10^-6}, {806.714, 
  8.7301*10^-6}, {814.048, 9.6006*10^-6}, {821.382, 
  0.000010563}, {828.715, 0.000011628}, {836.049, 
  0.000012808}, {843.383, 0.000014116}, {850.717, 
  0.000015566}, {858.05, 0.000017178}, {865.384, 
  0.00001897}, {872.718, 0.000020965}, {880.052, 
  0.00002319}, {887.385, 0.000025176}, {894.719, 
  0.000027359}, {902.053, 0.000029764}, {909.387, 
  0.000032418}, {916.72, 0.000035353}, {924.054, 
  0.00003861}, {931.388, 0.000042234}, {938.722, 
  0.00004628}, {946.055, 0.000050813}, {953.389, 
  0.000055914}, {960.723, 0.000061682}, {968.057, 0.000068239}}

the actual list is longer.
this is  F(x). I need this F(x) to use it in the integration.
for instance
P=Integrate[(Z)^(3/2)*x*Exp[-x/(Z)]*F[x],{x,0,inf}]


and after that plot P as a function of Z. how should it be solved?
I tried numerical integration with interpolation function, but it did not work.
what are the other options?
I also tried in Python but it results in zero.

Use f = Interpolation[list] to get an interpolation of the values in your list. Note you only have data for x from 733.376 to 968.057, so integrating from 0 to infinity is very dangerous (because you're extrapolating).

I’m voting to close this question because This is a math question and likely ill-posed at that since there is no indication of how the function might be extended outside the given data.

@ydd thanks for mentioning that. I  changed the integral bounds, but no difference

What is the expression of  Z?

@cvgmt  : it's what should be plotted. P(Z)

Interpolation does work, e.g.
data = {{733.376, 0}, {740.71, 3.7816*10^-6}, {748.044, 
    4.1438*10^-6}, {755.378, 4.5425*10^-6}, {762.711, 
    4.9811*10^-6}, {770.045, 5.4641*10^-6}, {777.379, 
    5.996*10^-6}, {784.713, 6.5824*10^-6}, {792.046, 
    7.2289*10^-6}, {799.38, 7.9423*10^-6}, {806.714, 
    8.7301*10^-6}, {814.048, 9.6006*10^-6}, {821.382, 
    0.000010563}, {828.715, 0.000011628}, {836.049, 
    0.000012808}, {843.383, 0.000014116}, {850.717, 
    0.000015566}, {858.05, 0.000017178}, {865.384, 
    0.00001897}, {872.718, 0.000020965}, {880.052, 
    0.00002319}, {887.385, 0.000025176}, {894.719, 
    0.000027359}, {902.053, 0.000029764}, {909.387, 
    0.000032418}, {916.72, 0.000035353}, {924.054, 
    0.00003861}, {931.388, 0.000042234}, {938.722, 
    0.00004628}, {946.055, 0.000050813}, {953.389, 
    0.000055914}, {960.723, 0.000061682}, {968.057, 0.000068239}};

Using Interpolation:
i = Interpolation[data];
mm = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]
Integrate[i[x], {x, Splice[mm]}]
Plot[i[x], {x, Splice[mm]}, Epilog -> Point[data]]

Integration yields: 0.00508758


well I don't need to plot the interpolation. I need to use F(x) to do the integration and there are other relations inside the integration which matter.

In order to answer it,
list = {{733.376, 0}, {740.71, 3.7816*10^-6}, {748.044, 
4.1438*10^-6}, {755.378, 4.5425*10^-6}, {762.711, 
4.9811*10^-6}, {770.045, 5.4641*10^-6}, {777.379, 
5.996*10^-6}, {784.713, 6.5824*10^-6}, {792.046, 
7.2289*10^-6}, {799.38, 7.9423*10^-6}, {806.714, 
8.7301*10^-6}, {814.048, 9.6006*10^-6}, {821.382, 
0.000010563}, {828.715, 0.000011628}, {836.049, 
0.000012808}, {843.383, 0.000014116}, {850.717, 
0.000015566}, {858.05, 0.000017178}, {865.384, 
0.00001897}, {872.718, 0.000020965}, {880.052, 
0.00002319}, {887.385, 0.000025176}, {894.719, 
0.000027359}, {902.053, 0.000029764}, {909.387, 
0.000032418}, {916.72, 0.000035353}, {924.054, 
0.00003861}, {931.388, 0.000042234}, {938.722, 
0.00004628}, {946.055, 0.000050813}, {953.389, 
0.000055914}, {960.723, 0.000061682}, {968.057, 0.000068239}};
Integrate[Interpolation[list, x], {x, 733.376, 968.057}]


0.00508758

It should be noticed
Integrate[Interpolation[list], {x, 733.376, 968.057}]

does not work.
Plot[Interpolation[list, x], {x, 733.376, 968.057}]



what's the reason that the interpolation does not work? and what's the solution?
